# How do I continue inserting all the rest of the rows even if one row being inserted hits a PRIMARY KEY constraint?

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, constraints, primary-key

Table link_instance_message has a PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT so that you cannot have duplicates in the table for instance_id, message_id combination. How can I not have it fail completely if there is already that intance_id, message_id combo in the table?

```
INSERT INTO link_instance_message
(instance_id, message_id)
select
ins.instance_id as instance_id, mess.message_id as message_id
from
instance as ins,
license as lic,
message as mess
where
ins.license_id = lic.license_id
and lic.license_key = '<INSERT GUID HERE>'
and mess.message_id = (select MAX(message_id) from message)
```

For example, let's say the insert statement above would insert 5 rows if no rows already existed in the table. But then let's say 1 row already exists that the insert statement above would try to insert again. How can have the other 4 rows be inserted while ignoring the violation of the PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT for the 1 row that already exists.

Comment: Luckily there is a guarantee that only one user would be running this statement at one time. :-)

Where would I put the not exists ... I tried that and fumbled a little.

Comment: As an aside, please stop using old-style joins. Those both look like cross joins to me; it is even less clear that you actually meant for one of them to be.

Comment: Oh, I am NOT a DBA so I don't know these things. I know enough to be dangerous lol. How would I change it to not use old-style joins?

Comment: `instance as ins inner join license as lic on ins.license_id = lic.license_id` - in my answer though, the join was not necessary, since you weren't materializing any columns from the license table; in this case, EXISTS has the potential to perform better.

Comment: I wrote about [old-style joins here](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins.aspx) and [the schema prefix here](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I think this pattern is better. You may need to escalate the transaction isolation to prevent race conditions and other concurrency issues.

```
DECLARE @message_id INT;

SELECT @message_id = MAX(message_id) FROM dbo.message;

INSERT dbo.link_instance_message -- always use schema prefix
  (instance_id, message_id)
SELECT i.instance_id, @message_id
FROM dbo.instance AS i
WHERE EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 FROM dbo.license 
    WHERE license_id = i.license_id 
    AND license_key = '<INSERT GUID HERE>'
)
AND NOT EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 FROM dbo.link_instance_message 
     WHERE instance_id = i.instance_id 
     AND message_id = @message_id
);
```

Comment: Luckily there is a guarantee that only one user would be running this statement at one time. :-) Where would I put the not exists ... I tried that and fumbled a little.

Comment: And I removed schema prefixes and identifiable table information that are company-specific for security purposes.

Comment: You are a boss. This worked perfectly how I wanted it to. :-)